# How to read data from a file (word document, excel) with format in Java?

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, formatting

I have a file formatting.doc. It has some text in it. Now I added some format to the text in the document. I have added space before the start of first paragraph, underlined some words, made some words in bold and centrally justified the paragraph.

In my application I tried to read the file using Apache POI and then display in PDF format using iText. But, the text that Apache POI returns is raw data. i.e. without any formatting.

Is there any way in Java to read the text of a file with all its formatting?

Comment: Please show some code. It's hard to tell what's wrong with no code at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best option is using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org). It uses Apache POI and a few other libraries and offer formatted extraction among other things.